# Extracting URL path to embedded resources from request in JMeter

Tags: url, jmeter, resources, extract

I need to extract URL path form one of the embedded resources as a variable or property.

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WusO.png)

I send request to https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi and want to extract eq. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css, or any of embedded resources.

I tryied extract URL with Regular Expression Extractor but I recieve only
VAL = https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using Regular Expression Extractor, to wit you will have only one single result from the last [SubResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult(org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult))

If you want to have URLs for all Embedded Resources as JMeter Variables you could do this using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), the example code would be something like:

```
prev.getSubResults().eachWithIndex { subresult, index ->
    vars.put('URL_' + (index + 1), subresult.getUrlAsString())
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Works fine thanks  !!! If anyone want to save URL's in properties use  prev.getSubResults().eachWithIndex { subresult, index ->
    props.put('URL_' + (index + 1), subresult.getUrlAsString())
}